# Add/commit to bare repo from a non-git folder

Tags: git, version-control, backup

I'm trying to hack git to do backup for me. The data is so large relatively and I cannot afford a working copy and a git repo on any of my hard drives.

So, I need to git add/commit to a bare repo from a non-git folder.

- Hard drive 1:  working copy / non-git
- Hard drive 2:  bare git repo

Goal: commit from hard drive 1 to hard drive 2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No need for a bare repo.

you can specify a different git folder:

```
git --git-dir=/other/drive/some/path add
```

alternatively you can specify a different working folder:

```
git --work-tree=/other/drive/some/path add
```

or combine them together to execute from arbitrary location.

Beware that not all commands work with this parameter. Stash is one.

Comment: To clarify: you don't need a bare repo, you just need a git directory in a different place from your work tree. This is how you do it.

Comment: Though, a bare and remote repository as you very smart suggest would occupy less space. +1

Comment: no. you would have 2 histories. you want just one repository but tinker where the history is stored. if you want to push to remote to do a backup of this "backup" then you can consider another git repo that's a remote.

Comment: I developed your answer to this:
git --git-dir=xx --work-tree=yy init

Comment: sweet! beware though that some commands can't handle those options. Stash is one of them :/ .. hope this gets fixed in future versions.

Comment: An alternate solution, if you want to avoid needing those options, would be to create the repo where you want the .git directory, with an empty work tree, and then use `git-new-workdir` (from git.git's contrib directory), which creates a .git directory with symlinks back to the original for most of the contents, so it doesn't take much space at all, but can be used as normal, with operations affecting the original repo through the symlinks.

Comment: Also, you probably want to just make an alias `mygit='git --git-dir=... --work-tree=...`. Saves a lot of typing and headache