# GUI for bare git repo

Tags: git, user-interface, git-bare

Is there a GUI for a bare git repo directory ( there is no working tree anywhere ) that I can:

- Check logs
- See the whole working tree structure for any commits

Regarding to why I need this:

My git is init as this:
  git --git-dir=xx --work-tree=yy init ( [Add/commit to bare repo from a non-git folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7700404/add-commit-to-bare-repo-from-a-non-git-folder) )

I couldn't find a tool can work with this situation ( separated working tree and repo )

Comment: Usually a bare repository is "somewhere in the wild" and you only work with a local clone on which you can use any gui you want. Whats wrong with that?

Comment: Why would you want to work with a bare repo directly?

Comment: I updated in the question. In short: git --git-dir=xx --work-tree=yy init

Comment: SVN can do it. Github also works. I need similar thing for my bare git repo.

Comment: gitk --all works fine from bare repos as well.

Comment: YES gitk works, after I set GIT_DIR and GIT_WORK_TREE. Thanks @AdamDymitruk

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your situation, you can do:

```
git --git-dir=xx --work-tree=yy gui
```

and visualize log etc.

Or, just clone the bare repo - `git clone path/to/bare.git .` and operate on that.

Note that you combine the `-n` and `-l` ( which is default for local clone anyway) you won't get a working directory and also, the objects and refs are hard-linked and you don't use up much space.

Comment: I know. My git repo is huge. I don't have space/time for it. Thanks!

Comment: @TomFishman - Also updated on space usage. And local clone doesn't take much time.

Comment: hardlinks are not supported on all OSes

Comment: @Tom: Arguably if your repo is too large for you to clone, then the same will be true for others, and you have much bigger problems than how to browse the commit log.

Answer (score 5):

**You can simply run gitk --all from the git folder you specified as the parameter and inspect your repo.**

For others that hit this question: if you are concerned about space taken up by a working directory, clone with the -n (no checkout option):

```
git clone -n <url to your repo>
```

Comment: I will try this. Assuming it doesn't duplicate any data. ( my repo is huge )

Comment: You should be able to run gitk --all from the .git folder (your xx folder)

Comment: `gitk --all` is very nice. You can even switch between a "patch" view and a "tree" view in it!